# openssl random pseudo bytes and bin2hex having lower case characters

Tags: aes, key

Got few question related with each other… it is regarding the Key to use in encryption. Generating a 32 byte key (256 bit) for AES-CBC-256 with PHP/openssl, to use in the `openssl_encrypt` function.

As I understand I can create a 32 byte string with the following php function:

```
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32, true);
```

1. First question, it will output strange characters (my charsets utf8), is the key correct with these strange characters? is the key valid to use?

   example output: `O�3sa��TX|~�!�Q8�]M�r��{���?��`

   If I convert each of those chars to binary digits I get:

   ```
   01001111 10110001 00110011 01110011 01100001 10111111 11011101 01010100
   01011000 01111100 01111110 11101010 00100001 10001011 01010001 00001110
   00111000 10111101 01011101 01001101 10100000 01110010 10101001 11001100
   01111011 10110001 11010011 11110001 00111111 00000110 11000110 11001011
   ```

   So it seems to be correct, I got 32x8 bits = 256 bit key…
2. Second question, is that one of the reasons why the key should be hex'ed, because it can out put unknown characters… and this way make it more readable, also for storage?

   $key_hex = bin2hex($key);

   output: `4fb1337361bfdd54587c7eea218b510e38bd5d4da072a9cc7bb1d3f13f06c6cb`
3. Third question, if I read about HEX it says it contains only `0-9` and `A-F`, why am I seeing lowercase characters in the `bin2hex` (php) output above?
4. Is it then safe to do `strtoupper()` so all get uppercase characters as it should?

   If I take the second character (the unknown one) from the raw key, which is b1 (B1) in hex, i.e. binary bits: `10110001`

   If I look it up on this website: http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/?start=0&end=400&cols=4&search=&show_uni_int=on&show_uni_hex=on&show_html_ent=on&show_raw_hex=on&show_raw_bin=on

   I do find B1 for `1011 0001`, but seems to be a part of a character which contain 2 or more bytes... is this maybe the reason why I am seeing it as an unknown character? as its just a random 8 bits...

   Maybe I am missing a few puzzle pieces here to get the overall picture... But I think in general the key should be fine and it can be hex'ed and uppercased and be used also in `openssl_encrypt`.

   But just want to be sure, that I not make any mistake with this, thats why I am posting this here... if someone could verify this.

Thank you

Comment: In general the answer is "yes" :) Note that you can generate any character encoding, including invalid ones. It depends on the default character encoding in use in PHP what is shown. What you get in return is a octet string (or byte array) instead of a character string, but as PHP is not strongly typed, it can be used as either.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the 2nd argument.  It has no effect on the result of the function.  You pass in a variable like `$cryptoStrong`, and the function will _set the value of that variable by reference_.  You can then check that value to see if the byte generation was cryptographically strong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) and 2) As per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), this would indeed be the correct way to use this function. You will note that in the example, `bin2hex` is used to make the string readable.

3) Both are valid, there is no difference between upper- and lowercase letters in the context of hexadecimal notation. Generally, a program which takes hexadecimal as input will accept both, but...

4) ... if you have a program which insists on the letters being uppercase, using `strtoupper` will work.